# SwiftUI Passing a changing function as a parameter to a custom component

Tags: swiftui

I would like to pass an evaluating function as a parameter to a custom component but it is not working. I am not sure if I should create a custom closure. Would love to hear your thoughts. Here is the code:

```
@State private var selectedBeautyFilter: BeautyLUT
...

CheckmarkView(isChecked: (selectedView == .none) ? true : false)
```

PS I am able to get the code working by just using a if..else statement but I insert CheckmarkView component twice (one for isChecked true and another one false)

Cheers

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell from the amount of code you've provided what you're trying to do. Can you provide some more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any function for `print("Hello 1")` or `print("Hello 2")` it is just for showing, for example like this: `customFunction = yourCustomFunctionName` in this example I send a custom function to a View. Even you can do same thing to send a function to another function no big issue, all possible.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var customFunction: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Spacer()

        Button("send func 1") {
            
            customFunction = { print("Hello 1") }
            
        }
        .padding()
        
        Button("send func 2") {
            
            customFunction = { print("Hello 2") }
            
        }
        .padding()
        
        Spacer()
        
        
        CustomView(customFunction: $customFunction)
     
        
        Spacer()
        
        
    }
}


struct CustomView: View {
    
    @Binding var customFunction: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {

        Button("run incoming func") {

            if let unwrappedFuc = customFunction { unwrappedFuc() } else { print("No function send!")}
            
        }
        .padding()
   
    }
}
```